# Virtual Box Disk Space and Resizing

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox

I am working on a mac and I am using VirtualBox running Ubuntu 12.1.

For some reason this morning Mysql wont start up but digging into the system I think its to do with disk space.

Running df -h Im getting:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root  7.2G  6.9G     0 100% /
udev                     241M  4.0K  241M   1% /dev
tmpfs                    100M  300K   99M   1% /run
none                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                     249M     0  249M   0% /run/shm
none                     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow                 1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
/dev/sda1                228M   98M  118M  46% /boot
```

So I went to the vdi file and run the following.

```
$ VBoxManage modifyhd APR.vdi --resize 51200
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

So on virtual box interface its showing size as 50Gig now:

[image]

But restarting the server and running df -h Im still getting same numbers.

Is there a step I have missed??

Hope you can advise.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend the disk within Ubuntu as well. You can use something like `gparted` to do this.

Comment: The disk has been resized but the filesystem hasn't. It looks like you're running LVM, if you prefer using the CLI you'll need tools like `vgextend`,  `lvextend` and `resize2fs`. You might find an example guide [like this one](http://www.greyoak.com/lvmdrive.html) useful. Keep a backup of your virtual disk before running these commands as they can be deleterious if used incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry but I'm pretty noob to this. Its only going to be by command line as its a ubuntu server. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: You can boot the VM off a gparted ISO and make the changes there.  It's pretty straightforward.